# Listview is not sliding in while clicking action bar in android

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have implemented a navigation drawer menu using getsupportactionbar and list view. While clicking the action bar, the listview is not moving. In facebook and google+ right hand side component will also move. Can anybody tell me how to also move the listview? Is it possible to implement in android, and if yes can anybody me tell how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible using navigation drawer. You can try that with [sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)